# Filters for finding useful answers

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

**Background**

I was looking at a [recently asked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744191/raid6-won-t-load#comment1415082_74419), where the asker was clearly out of their depth with an issue. The gist was essentially "I've got this problem, help please, because I've no idea how to fix this".

Rather than simply VTC as lacking details [I suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744191/raid6-won-t-load#comment1415052_744191) they look at questions and answers for similarly tagged questions to see what commands need to be run and added to the question to provide enough information for it to be answerable.

**Issue**

Although it's possible to filter the tagged question list by "unanswered", there are no options *in the drop-down Filter* to search for questions with decent answers. The closest is "Has bounty", but even that is no guarantee of a decent answer. (There are options for knowledgeable people to use in the search query, but I'm talking about the Filter button/drop-down.)

Example: [raid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raid) - how do you really find useful questions that have answers, or even accepted answers?

**Request**

Add additional drop-down filter options:

- questions with answers
- questions with upvoted answers
- questions with an accepted answer

Comment: The last bit, questions with accepted answers, is `hasaccepted:true`. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/searching  Suggestion for search starting point: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Braid%5D+hasaccepted%3Atrue+views%3A5000+votes%3A10

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you. However it's not possible to use the obvious filter to find these

Comment: Mobile now, but https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/searching has some useful operators for this: `answers:1..` and `hasaccepted:yes`

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks. I've updated the text to highlight this isn't a general "how to search" question

Comment: Gotcha; sorry for the misunderstanding! I should have realized with the [tag:feature-request].  Before I see myself completely out, maybe this would be an opportunity for a canonical RAID Q&A, or perhaps some helpful bits on the [tag wiki](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/raid/info)?

Comment: I would agree that a few extra options in the "filter by" dropdown would help. Particularly having "accepted answers" would give better search results. This is not specific to RAID Q&A but for general searches.